# Как правильно инициализировать переменную строкой в PHP?

Tags: php

Нашел несколько вариантов. Особенно смущает первый:

```
<?php

$a = a;
$b = 'b';
$c = "c";

var_dump($a);
var_dump($b);
var_dump($c);
```

Вывод:

```
string(1) "a"
string(1) "b"
string(1) "c"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если бы у вас были включены ошибки, то первый вариант бы ругнулся (а остальные два вполне валидны). Дело в том, что при нахождении простого слова без $-префикса PHP воспринимает его как название константы. В случае, если скрипт пытается получить доступ к необъявленной константе, PHP ругнется то ли предупреждением, то ли ошибкой, и вернет само название константы, то есть в данном случае идет обращение к константе а, ее ненахождение и возврат самого имени константы.

Что до двух остальных случаев, то они идетичны, за исключением того, что строки в двойных кавычках [интерполируются](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.simple).